# Proof of "The sum of squared distances from the points to the line is a minimum"

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, singular-values, principal-component-analysis

I'm reading "Introduction to linear algebra" of Gillbert Strang.
PCA by SVD section.
Text says that the sum of squared distances from the points to the line is a minimum and author is trying to proof that:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} ||a_{k}||^2=\sum_{k=1}^{n}|a_{k}^Tu_{1}|^2 + \sum_{k=1}^{n}|a_{k}^Tu_{2}|^2$$
I don't really understand why length squared of columns of A is a sum of squares of inner products of its columns with singular eigenvectors.
**So my first question could you please explain this part for me?**
Next sentence is "The first sum on the right
is $$u_{1}^TAA^Tu_{1}$$"

So how did
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}|a_{k}^Tu_{1}|^2$$
transform to $$u_{1}^TAA^Tu_{1}$$ ?

As I understand $$|a_{k}^Tu_1|^2$$
is just a sum of squares of the numbers of multiplications(inner products) of all columns with first singular eigenvector, right?

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't directly answer the question,
but it is a method I came up with
about 30 years ago
for finding the line
which minimizes
the sum of the squares
of the distances to a set of 2d points.

This was reformatted from
LaTeX to MathJax,
so there are some
incomplete conversions.

I may have submitted this before -
I often forget things like that.

---

The problem investigated here
is that of fitting a straight line
to a set of data points.
The fit is intended to be
independent of the coordinate system
in the sense that,
if the data points are
rotated or shifted,
the resulting line
will be the same
relative to the points.

The standard least squares fitted line
does not satisfy this criteria,
because the error in the fit
for each point
is considered to be
the distance from the point to the line
parallel to one of the
ordinate axes.
When the axes are rotated,
the distance changes.

We choose to use the actual distance
from the point to the line
as the error in the fit.
This yields an error
which is invariant
under translations and rotations.

No claim is made about
the originality of these results.
This is an independent derivation
(made in 1985)
of an often discovered technique.

\section{The polar form of the equation of a straight line}

There are a number of forms
that the equation of
a straight line can take
(e.g.,
point-slope, intersection with axes,
$y~=~mx+b$).

The form most useful
for our purpose
is the $polar$ form.
In this form,
a line $L$
is determined by
its distance r from the origin
and the angle $\theta$
that the normal from the origin
to the line
makes with the $x$ axis,
the angle being measured
counterclockwise.

The equation of $L$
in terms of r and $\theta$
is
$\eqalignno{L:~~   
x\cos \theta + y \sin \theta ~=~r.&(1)}$

This can be verified
by noting that
$x~=~r/\cos\theta$ at $y~=~0$
and
$y~=~r/\sin\theta$ at $x~=~0$.

Another derivation
of equation (1) for $L$
is as follows:
Let $(x,y)$ be a point on $L$,
$d$ the distance of
$(x,y)$ from the origin,
and $\phi$ the angle
that the line from the origin
to $(x, y)$
makes with the $x$-axis.
The angle between this line
and the normal to $L$
is easily seen to be
$\theta-\phi$.
Thus,
$r/d ~=~\cos(\theta-\phi)$.
Since
$x~=~d\cos \phi$
and $y~=~d\sin \phi$,
$$\eqalignno{
x \cos \theta + y \sin \theta
&~=~ d \cos (\theta-\phi)\cr
&~=~ r.\cr
}$$
This derivation,
though more complicated than
the preceding one,
has the advantage of
also giving explicit formulae
for $x$ and $y$
in terms of $r$, $\theta$, and $\phi$,
$$x~=~{r\cos\phi \over \cos(\theta-\phi)}
\quad{\rm and}\quad
y~=~{r\sin\phi \over \cos(\theta-\phi)}.$$

The polar form for
the equation of $L$
is so useful
because
the distance from
any point $(u, v)$
to $L$
is $u\cos \theta + v \sin \theta - r$.
To show this,
consider the line $L'$
through $(u, v)$
that is parallel to $L$,
is $u\cos\theta+v\sin\theta-r$}
If $d$ is the distance
from $L'$ to $L$,
which is also the distance
from $(u, v)$ to $L$,
the equation of $L'$ is
$x\cos\theta+y\sin\theta~=~d+r$,
since $L$ and $L'$ are parallel.
Since $(u, v)$ is on $L'$,
$u\cos\theta+v\sin\theta~=~d+r$,
so that,
as claimed,
$d~=~u\cos\theta+y\sin\theta-r$.

\section{Evaluating the mean squared error}

We now define some
notation and abbreviations.
Let $c~=~\cos \theta$ and
$s~=~\sin \theta$,
so the equation of $L$ is
$cx+sy~=~r$.
The data points
used to fit $L$
are $(x_i, y_i)$
for $i=1$ to $n$
(i.e.,
there are $n$ points).
For any expression f,
we define $\overline{f} $
to be the average of f
over all the data points,
so that
$$\overline{f} ~=~(1/n)\sum_{i=1}^n f_i.$$

For example,
$\overline{x} ~=~(1/n)\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$,
and
$\overline{xy} ~=~(1/n)\sum_{i=1}^n x_i y_i$.

Note:
We can also define
$\overline{f} $
to be a weighted mean
$$\overline{f} ~=~{\sum_{i=1}^n f_i w_i \over \sum_{i=1}^n w_i}$$
where each $w_i > 0$,
and the results which follow
are not affected at all.

If $p$ and $q$ are any of $x$ and $y$,
we define
$$\langle p,q\rangle ~=~\overline{pq} -\overline{p}\ \overline{q},$$
the covariance
between the variables $p$ and $q$.
For example,
$$\langle x,x\rangle ~=~\overline{x^2}-\overline{x}^2
\quad{\rm and}\quad
\langle x,y\rangle ~=~\overline{xy}-\overline{x}\ \overline{y}.$$

If D is the mean squared error
of $L$,
then
$$\eqalignno{
D &~=~ \overline{({\rm distance\;from\;point\;}i{\rm\;to\;}L)^2} \cr
&~=~ \overline{d^2}\cr
&~=~ \overline{(cx+sy-r)^2} \cr
&~=~ \overline{c^2x^2+s^2y^2+r^2 +
2csxy-2crx-2sry} \cr
}$$
so that
$$\eqalignno{D~=~ c^2\overline{x^2} +s^2\overline{y^2} +r^2+
2sc\overline{xy} -2cr\overline{x} -2sr\overline{y} .
&(2)}$$

\section{Minimizing the mean squared error}

If $L$ is to be
the best fitting line
in the least mean squared sense,
we must have
$${\partial D \over \partial r}~=~0
{\rm \quad and \quad}
{\partial D \over \partial \theta}~=~0.$$

Since
${\partial D \over \partial r}
=2r-2c\overline{x}-2s\overline{y}
$,
this implies that
$r
=c\overline{x}+s\overline{y}
$.
Since the equation of the line is
$cx+sy = r$,
this implies that
the line passes through
$(\overline{x}, \overline{y})
$.

$\begin{array}\\
0
&={\partial D \over \partial \theta} \\
&={\partial \over \partial \theta}(c^2\overline{x^2} +s^2\overline{y^2} +r^2+
2sc\overline{xy} -2cr\overline{x} -2sr\overline{y})\\
&=-2cs\overline{x^2} +2cs\overline{y^2} +
2(c^2-s^2)\overline{xy} +2sr\overline{x} -2cr\overline{y}\\
&=2cs(\overline{y^2} -\overline{x^2}) +
2(c^2-s^2)\overline{xy} +2r(s\overline{x} -c\overline{y})\\
&=2cs(\overline{y^2} -\overline{x^2}) +
2(c^2-s^2)\overline{xy} +2(c\overline{x}+s\overline{y})(s\overline{x} -c\overline{y})\\
&=2cs(\overline{y^2} -\overline{x^2}) +
2(c^2-s^2)\overline{xy} 
+2(cs\overline{x}^2-(s^2-c^2)\overline{x}\ \overline{y}-cs\overline{y}^2)\\
&=2cs(\overline{y^2}-\overline{y}^2
 -\overline{x^2} +\overline{x}^2)
+2(c^2-s^2)(\overline{xy}-\overline{x}\ \overline{y})\\
&=2cs(\langle y, y\rangle-\langle x, x\rangle)
+2(c^2-s^2)\langle x, y\rangle\\
&=\sin(2\theta)(\langle y, y\rangle-\langle x, x\rangle)
+2\cos(2\theta)\langle x, y\rangle\\
\\
\end{array}
$

From this,
$\theta$ can be determined.

However,
the values of $r$ and $\theta$
that minimize $D$
can also be found without using any calculus.
This will now be done
by writing $D$
as the sum of terms which,
when independently minimized,
give the desired values
for $r$ and $\theta$.
$$\eqalignno{
D&~=~ c^2\overline{x^2} +s^2\overline{y^2} +r^2+
2sc\overline{xy} -2cr\overline{x} -2sr\overline{y}\cr
&=~ c^2\overline{x^2} +s^2\overline{y^2} +2sc\overline{xy}
+r^2 -2r(c\overline{x} +s\overline{y})\cr
&=~ c^2\overline{x^2} +s^2\overline{y^2} +2sc\overline{xy}
+(r-c\overline{x} -s\overline{y})^2
 -(c\overline{x} +s\overline{y})^2\cr
&=~c^2(\overline{x^2}-\overline{x}^2) 
+ s^2(\overline{y^2}-\overline{y}^2)
 + 2sc(\overline{xy}-\overline{x}\overline{y})
+(r-c\overline{x} -s\overline{y})^2\cr
&=~c^2\langle x,x\rangle  + s^2\langle y,y\rangle +2sc\langle x,y\rangle 
 +(r-c\overline{x} -s\overline{y})^2.&(3)\cr
}$$
Letting $S=\sin 2\theta =2sc$
and $C=\cos 2\theta=c^2-s^2$,
since
$c^2=(1+C)/2$ and
$s^2=(1-C)/2$,

$$\eqalignno{
D~&=~\frac{1+C}{2}\langle x,x\rangle  + \frac{1-C}{2}\langle y,y\rangle +S\langle x,y\rangle 
 +(r-c\overline{x} -s\overline{y})^2\cr
~&=~{\langle x,x\rangle +\langle y,y\rangle  \over 2}
+ C {\langle x,x\rangle-\langle x,y \rangle \over 2}
 + S \langle x,y\rangle 
+(r-c\overline{x} -s\overline{y})^2\cr
&=~D_1+C~D_2+S~D_3
+(r-c\overline{x} -s\overline{y})^2&(4)\cr
}
$$

where
$$\eqalignno{
D_1&~=~{\langle x,x\rangle  +\langle y,y\rangle  \over 2},&(5a)\cr
D_2&~=~{\langle x,x\rangle  -\langle y,y\rangle  \over 2},&(5b)\cr
D_3&~=~\langle x,y\rangle .&(5c)\cr
}$$
Defining $R$ and $\phi$ by
$$\eqalignno{D_2~=~R\cos\phi\quad
{\rm and}\quad
D_3~=~R\sin\phi, &(6)}$$
where
$R \ge 0$
and
$0 \le \phi < 2\pi$,
$$\eqalignno{
D~&=~D_1+C~D_2+S~D_3
+(r-c\overline{x} -s\overline{y})^2\cr
&=~D_1+R\cos 2\theta\cos\phi+R\sin 2\theta\sin\phi
+(r-c\overline{x} -s\overline{y})^2\cr
&=~D_1+R\cos(2\theta-\phi)
+(r-c\overline{x} -s\overline{y})^2.&(7)\cr
}$$
This is the desired
expression for $D$.

Since
$\cos(2\theta-\phi) \ge -1$
and
$(r-c\overline{x}-s\overline{y})^2 \ge 0$,
$D \ge D_1-R$.
By choosing
$$\eqalignno{
\theta~&=~{\phi+\pi \over 2}
\quad{\rm and}\quad
r~=~\overline{x}\cos\theta + \overline{y}\sin\theta,
&(8)}$$
$D$ will achieve its minimum value
$$\eqalignno{
D~&=~D_1 - R.
& (9)}$$

\section{Summary of line fitting algorithm}

The technique for fitting a line
to a set of data points is:

1.
Gather the needed mean values:
$\overline{x}$, $\overline{y}$,
$\overline{xy}$, $\overline{x^2}$,
and $\overline{y^2}$.

2.
Using $\langle p,q\rangle ~=~\overline{pq}-\overline{p}\ \overline{q}$,
compute the covariances
$\langle x,x\rangle $, $\langle y,y\rangle $, and $\langle x,y\rangle $
and set
$$\eqalignno{
D_1&~=~{\langle x,x\rangle  +\langle y,y\rangle  \over 2},\cr
D_2&~=~{\langle x,x\rangle  -\langle y,y\rangle  \over 2},\cr
D_3&~=~\langle x,y\rangle .\cr
}$$

3.
Get the mean squared error $D$ by
$$R~=~\sqrt{D_2^2 + D_3^2}$$
and
$$D~=~D_1 - R.$$

4.
To find $r$ and $\theta$,
the parameters of $L$
when in polar form,
set
$\phi$ to the value of
$\tan^{-1}(D_3 / D_2)$
such that
$D_2~=~R\cos\phi$
and
$D_3~=~R\sin\phi$.
(This can be done in Fortran
using the ATAN2 function.)
Then
$$\theta~=~{\phi+\pi \over 2}
\quad{\rm and}\quad
r~=~\overline{x}\cos\theta + \overline{y}\sin\theta.$$